# Folders With Custom Icons Problem

Tags: folders, desktop

On my desktop I have some folders, they all have custom icons.

I'm now trying to add alias' to my desktop with custom icons, how can this be done?

I've tried

1. Custom icons on a alias folder
2. Creating symbolic links to all the folders inside the folder (like below)

   ln -s ~/Google\ Drive/Personal ~/Desktop/Google\ Drive

The second option has the bottleneck of not being dynamic; if I add a folder/file to *~/Google\ Drive*, I'll need to create a new symbolic link and visa versa, if I delete a folder I'll need to delete the folder which represents the symbolic.

I could run a script that does this but this to me seems like i'm over complicating the problem.

Something like

```
# bash
rm -r ~/Desktop/Google\ Drive/*
rm ~/Desktop/Google\ Drive/*
ln -s ~/Google\ Drive/* ~/Desktop/Google\ Drive
```

Update:
Using @frdmn methods I get exactly what I want but using my method above I get what I want, bar trivial excess computation, but I also get the ability to show the number of items in the folder. Which could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the icon to the original folder of the alias. Then recreate it and it should have the same icon.